# How to change the toolbar when I change from an activity to a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, kotlin, android-toolbar

I have an Activity, a Toolbar and several fragments, how can I change the toolbar passed to a fragment from MainActivity

i've tried calling the toolbar from fragment1.xml but it show two Toolbars one above the other

This is where I called the fragment

```java
        R.id.menu_acercade -> {
                    binding.navegacionInferior.selectedItemId = item.itemId
                    cerrarDrawer()
                    false
                }
        R.id.menu_acercade -> {
                            intercalarIconosMenu(false)
                            intercalarPagers(true)
                            binding.navegacionInferior.menu.getItem(2).isCheckable = true  //binding.navegacionInferior.menu.getItem(2).isCheckable = true
                            binding.viewpagerSecciones.setCurrentItem(0, true) //antes 0
                            true
                        }
```

Here is the XML of the fragment in which I want to change the ActionBar, but whenever I add the layou tag it add another Actionbar example

[two ActionBars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIiur.jpg)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!--<include layout="@layout/toolbar_atras" />-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="542dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:src="@drawable/about_logo" />
            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                style="@style/Titulo.Principal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:text="@string/menu_opcion_acercade" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
                android:textColor="@color/colorTexto" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
                android:text="Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
                android:textColor="@color/colorTexto" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navegacionInferior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:background="@color/colorBlanco"
            android:paddingEnd="0dp"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            app:elevation="16dp"
            app:itemBackground="@drawable/fondo_navegacioninferior"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimario"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimario"
            tools:menu="@menu/menu_inferior" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Please add XML file

Comment: @CesarJoelGurrola Check my answer , I've also given an example on how the sequence of layout should be, along with how to update the title within a fragment.

Answer (score -1):

Inside your Activity

```
setSupportActionBar(yourToolbar)
supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
```

In Your Fragment

```
(activity as? AppCompatActivity)?.supportActionBar?.title = "Your Title"
```

Your Activity layout should probably follow the sequence in the below example

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:id="@+id/main_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- AppBarLayout is a wrapper for a Toolbar -->
<!-- Note that AppBarLayout expects to be the first child nested within a CoordinatorLayout -->
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<!-- FrameLayout can be used to insert fragments to display the content of the screen -->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: didn't work I  tried 
(activity as? AppCompatActivity)?.setSupportActionBar(findViewById(toolbar)), any comments? Greets

Comment: May I know why you're setting up the toolbar again within your fragment ? Set the toolbar only inside your MainActivity, which adds/replaces the fragment. Let the fragment just update the title , instead of setting up toolbar, this will prevent showing two Toolbars one above the other

Comment: it's because i need to change it to a (backToolbar) instead the menu one, 
I need to:
-  in Main Activity -> MenuToolbar
-  in Fragment1 -> BackToolbar any idea how can I achieve this?